# Find the particular solution of the given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If possible, is anyone able to give me the solution and working to this?

Am I correct in saying that I first need to gain the General solution followed by the particular solution? Have been struggling with this for about an hour. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + 3yx^3 = 0$$

When $y(0) = 1$

So multiply up by dx. And then I need to get the x out of 3yx^3. Again not sure how to do that.

Comment: Seperate the variables.

Comment: It is a separable equation...

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Yes I have read that, but also struggling to get my head around the separation. (Have been thrown in the deep end so I'm very much a novice). Ideally I need to have y on the left and then x on the right.

Comment: Well, how could you do so?

Comment: So multiply up by dx. And then I need to get the x out of 3yx^3. Again not sure how to do that.

Comment: I will give you a hint. If you subtract ${3yx^3}$ from both sides, is there anything you can do then to separate the variables?

Comment: so you then have dy/dx = -3yx^3. Would you then times by dx to get dy = -3yx^3 dx. Still not sure of the y in the second part though.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through separable equations again. If you have a Differential Equation of the form

$${\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{f(x)}{g(y)}}$$

Then you can do the following:

$${g(y)dy=f(x)dx}$$

integrate both sides

$${\int g(y) dy = \int f(x)dx}$$

Then after integration, (usually) you can then rearrange for $y$. This is just the method, though. This doesn't explain why the method works (treating ${dy}$ and ${dx}$ just as numbers is a bad thing to do, in this case it works - but **why** it works needs more justification). If you are just starting out though - it can be helpful getting used to using a method mechanically before learning rigorously why it works. Make sure that eventually - you do learn why though, otherwise you could make many errors. Plus - the reasons why things work in Mathematics usually are very interesting.

Once you rearrange and get

$${\frac{dy}{dx}=-3yx^3}$$

can you now identify ${f(x)}$ and ${g(y)}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-3yx^3$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-3x^3}{y^{-1}}$$
$$y^{-1}dy=-3x^3dx$$
$$\int y^{-1}dy=\int-3x^3dx$$
$$\ln(y)=\frac{-3}{4}x^4+c_{1}$$
$$y=e^{\frac{-3}{4}x^4+c_{1}}$$
Solve for $c_{1}$ with the given initial condition.